# Is there any alternative to function pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c

I am a novice c++ programmer who kept an idea that function pointers are a thing of C and OOP in C++ does not recommend its usage.

I know what I write here is vague/broad. But it will be great if somebody could comment whether my idea is completely wrong or something sensible.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not really clear what you're trying to achieve with function pointers?

Comment: I am asking it generally. Sorry for being vague here. Just like C++ recommend usage of const instead of #define, in a similar way is there any recommendation not to use function pointers.

Comment: Not really. There's nothing inherently bad about function pointers. There's always bad usage of them however ;) (other than the cache miss you'll probably get with your instruction cache)

Comment: @MattD : Thanks for the help. I was somehow having an idea that we should not use fp in c++ if possible.

Comment: @NeonGlow There is no rule saying you shouldn't use them, but there are probably ways of structuring your code in such a way that you don't need them. It all depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I use function pointers to implement Asynchronous Callbacks.  I think most other things like a runtime Strategy pattern can be done with class hierarchies.

Comment: What about `std::function` (in the `<functional>` header)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there is any widely accepted advice to avoid function pointers however there are some alternatives.

**[Virtual methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)**
One of the most common uses of function pointers in C is to implement dynamic dispatch. In C++ however this can be done for you (for single dispatch) by using virtual functions, indeed the usual implementation is that the compiler creates essentially a [table of function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

**[Functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)**

in the C++ sense, a functor is a small utility class that overloads operator() to behave like a first class function, as it's a normal class you can pass its objects around like any other objects without need for function pointers.

**[Lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B)**

essentially provide a more convenient way to declare functors inline.

**[Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29)**

Provide a generic way to use/consume function pointers, functors or lambdas. So you can write [higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) without needing function pointers, either by using a `std::function` parameter or directly using a template parameter.

Comment: Might be useful to mention `std::bind` and `std::function<ReturnType(ArgsTypes)>`. The first creates functors and the second is a generic functor holder.

Comment: added std::function, not added bind as I'm not sure it really answers the question, while it does create a new functor its more about partially applying a functor, no?

Comment: Also: **pointers to non-static member functions**.

Comment: @jk. : `bind` will partially apply functors, yes, but also many other callable things. Including those pointers to non-static member functions, which need an object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example where use of *member function pointer - within a class, as an implementation detail* - is perfectly acceptable, if one works with performance-sensitive code for different CPU architectures.

See the [C++ FAQs](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html) for the proper use of member function pointer. It requires a different syntax than static function pointers.

(Thanks for [Kaz](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213631/is-there-any-alternative-to-function-pointers-in-c#comment421974_213635) for the suggestion.)

```
class SomePerformanceCriticalOperation
{
private:
    // the type declaration of a member function pointer

    typedef int (SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::*ProcessPtr)(size_t bytesToProcess, void* dataPtr);

    // the instance of a member function pointer, to be assigned to a member function
    // (inside the constructor)
    ProcessPtr m_ptr;

public:
    SomePerformanceCriticalOperation()
    {
        cpu_features feat = ::GetCpuFeatures();
        if (TestBit(feat, cpu_features_SSE41))
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_SSE41;
        else if (TestBit(feat, cpu_features_SSSE3))
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_SSSE3;
        else if (TestBit(feat, cpu_features_SSE3))
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_SSE3;
        else if (TestBit(feat, cpu_features_SSE2))
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_SSE2;
        else if (TestBit(feat, cpu_features_MMX))
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_MMX;
        else 
            m_ptr = &SomePerformanceCriticalOperation::Process_CPlusPlus;
    }

    // The CPU-specific functions, as usual. (Omitted.)

    int Process_SSE41(size_t bytesToProcess, void* dataPtr) { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly C programmers used to use function pointers a lot, but most of those uses have been surpassed with OO alternatives - though they might not be obvious without examining the problem being solved rather than the solution itself.  For example, they were popular in implementing state machines but a C++ programmer would prefer to use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

One concept they are still necessary for is implementing a delegate (possibly the only reason to use one in the 21st century!?).  Provided as part of the language in other places the poor c++ developer still has to write his own - but it's fun to do (no!?) and you can find a description of how to do it here:  [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568150/what-is-a-c-delegate/9568226#9568226)